# How can we get File() type object in Java from S3 amazon server open file URL?

Tags: java, file-io, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a cloud application having public URLs of files stored on S3 Amazon server i want to get File() object from that URL like:

```
File file = new File("https://jcomplycustomers.s3.amazonaws.com/business%2FLite%2Fe38f3d28-cf78-4b74-9158-3f260782a123%2FLibrary%2Fcea3737f-25ed-4473-b340-27ec257b59f3.docx");
```

but failed to get this file, exception return by the system is 'File doesn't exist', but if i paste this URL in browser, browser open this file.

I have check this with converting URL to URI and try to get object but failed. same exception there as well.

Actually i don't want to first download this file and again access with that local URL. and don't want to convert it in streams etc

Now my problem is only this how can i get object of File() from this public URL?

Answer (score 4):

> How can we get File() type object in Java from S3 amazon server open file URL?

You can't. The question doesn't make sense. A URL represents a resource which is usually remote. A `File` represents a filename on a filesystem accessible to your computer.

If you're trying to *download* the file, use `URL.openConnection()`, or `URL.openStream(),` etc.

If you're not, as you claim, you will have to explain exactly what you mean by 'get object of `File()` from this public URL'.

Comment: In java File class have also two type of constructors, one is path name and second is URI, if we are going to getting file object from URI it is returning a file not found error from public URI of file stored on amazon S3 server.
And for your kind information for getting resource from remote or local system File class have multiple constructors in java.
In my question i have mentioned that i don't want to download file first and then access from local. I just directly want to get File object from that URL.
what type of clarity you need here...? Mr @EJP

Comment: @IrfamNasim For your kind information I was using Java in 1997 and am in no need your advice about the constructors of `File.` And what kind of clarity do you need about 'you can't'?